# Virtual Memory on linux

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, virtual-memory

Virtual pages are mapped to physical pages in the VM mechanism. The physical pages are evicted once a new page must be paged in.
I always assumed that the page-in/page-out was either to the swap area or the file region that has been actually mapped to the VM.
I have read that Linux on start up maps all the physical pages to virtual pages (and that is why the monitoring tools show much memory kept by the kernel I guess).
So my question is, what is the benefit of this approach? A virtual page does not physically exist on disk until a physical page has been evicted and the costly part is to page in and out a page and this is not avoided. Additionally it seems to me it is more complicated to passing all these pages originally reserved for the kernel to the various processes that request them.
What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 0):

Mapping all of the physical pages simplifies loading something into about-to-be-initialized memory.  The initial page mapping is not assigned to any process (just the kernel), but doing so simplifies and speeds up the i/o and/or copying of data, code, kernel structures to freshly allocated memory, maybe just with a `memcpy()` or `memset()`.

Philosophically, virtual memory pages should not be considered only mapped to part of a file:  they can be stack, heap, filesystem associative cache, or driver data structures.  In those cases, the *virtual space* would not be mapped to anything.

I haven't looked at the relevant source code in years, but paging to a swap file tends to be avoided, at least on modern systems with 1+G of memory.  It is at least twice as efficient (and likely 10+ times) to unmap some readonly page which hasn't been accessed in a long time and remap that to whatever is currently needed.  Only a modified page need be written to swap.

If you want to see drastically different paging and swap conditions, tell the kernel to use less memory.  Add `mem=64M` (or less) to the Linux boot arguments.

Comment: 1)`...doing so simplifies and speeds up the i/o and/or copying of data...` but what is the overhead that is actually avoided?If the page was not mapped the only overhead would be to add it to the Page Table.Right? The rest i.e. the copy would be the same.Is the PT modification so expensive or am I confused here? 2)`.... It is at least twice as efficient (and likely 10+ times) to unmap some readonly page...` but if the swap is not used then the VM size is the same as the physical memory.I thought that the VM size = swap + physical memory, so the more swap space the better.

Answer (score -1):

Linux virtual memory (virtual memory in general) is used to abstract physical memory to allow for operating system control over memory access.  The kernel maintains the page table that maps from the virtual addresses to physical addresses.

Paging memory is used to refer to pages currently stored on disk (swap) being brought into memory.  Paging memory out refers to writing the page to disk (swap) and being cleared from memory.  This allows more frequently used pages to be kept in faster storage, and less frequently used pages to be kept on slower storage.

Virtual memory also allows the operating system and processes to use more memory than actual physical memory exists on the system.

Comment: My question is what is the benefit of Linux approach to map *all* the physical pages to a VM page on start up? The cost of swapping is not avoided anyway.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it actually does since a kernel needs to map pages on demand.  For example, consider `sbrk` or `mmap`, or even just a page fault on a stack address.  The kernel does have to initialize the page table on boot and tell the CPU where the page table is though.

Comment: @Cratylus Maybe you're talking about free pages? Physical memory needs to be tracked in order to actually allocate it. This isn't unique to any operating system.  After boot, memory needs to be accessed via the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) as well, which needs to assume the page table structure is valid.